# store ncurses cursor position as variable

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm printing text at a location: `(10, 10)`.

- Waiting for input,
- clearing screen,
- doing it again.

When I print text, it moves the cursor to the end of the line. How do I get that X, Y position, and store it as a variable?

I want to do this so I can draw an animated box around the text.

I know there is `getyx(window, y, x)`, but it has a `void` return.

I tried to use it, yet it does not change `x` and `y`'s values, it will still print at `0, 0`. 
I can't understand how to use this method to do anything.

```
x = y = 0;
getyx(screen, y, x);
move(y, x);
printw("YX TEST"); // prints at 0,0 (bad)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
yPos = getY(screen);
xPos = getX(screen);
```

Where I can then process coordinates from that information ?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Please, have a look at [getyx(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getyx). _The **getyx** macro places the current cursor position of the given window in the two integer variables y and x._ You have to provide `int x, y;` and call the macro. Afterwards, `x` and `y` are assigned with cursor position.

Comment: OP says that they've tried that, and included the relevant code sample showing it doesn't do what they want.

Comment: `getyx` is a macro which uses the *names* of `y` and `x` to store the current position. It is a very unusual thing to do in C, since the language itself does not have such a calling convention. Can you provide a more complete code example? From what you have written there, we cannot see, where the cursor *should* be, when `getyx` is called.

Comment: @Tas So, he did something else wrong? A [mcve] would help to clarify this. ;-)

Comment: _I know there is getyx(window, y, x), but it has a void return._ It's a macro - it hasn't any return. (It expands probably to one or more statements.)

Comment: `static inline int getX(WINDOW *win) { int x, y; getxy(win, x, y); return x; } static inline int getY(WINDOW *win) { int x, y; getxy(win, x, y); return y; }` ?

Comment: What is the initialization of `screen`? Are you using the return value of `initscr()` and using the value or using the value of `newwin`? If the latter, you have two windows, you need to draw on the correct one (use `wprintw(scree, ..`` and `wmove(screen, ...)` `wrefresh(screen)`)

Comment: @UniversE the cursor is in the location it "should be", I'm just trying to get it's coordinates, and store it in a x and y variable, and I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: What is the declaration and where it the variable `screen` assigned? Is it `WINDOW *screen = initscr()` or `WINDOW *screen = newwin(...)` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk I have `initscr();`
  `WINDOW* screen = newwin(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a second window and used that second window while still drawing on [stdscr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/stdscr.html).
I can reproduce Your issue is with:

```
WINDOW *w1 = initscr();
WINDOW *w2 = newwin(LINES, COLS, 0, 0);
move(10, 10); // this moves the cursor on w1 or stdscr to (10, 10)
printw("YX TEST"); // this draws on w1, ie. stdscr the default screen
// now the cursor on w1 is on (10, 15) and cursor on w2 is on (0,0)
int x, y;
getxy(w2, x, y); // this gets the position of w2 window, which stayed at (0,0)
getxy(w1, x, y); // this will get you the position in w1 window, ie (10, 15)
refresh(); // this will draw window w1 on the screen, ie. `YX TEST`
wrefresh(w2); // this will draw nothing on the screen, as window w2 is empty
```

If you have two windows, and draw on one and get the cursor positions from the second, you will get strange results.
The following:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

void mybox(WINDOW *w, int sx, int sy, int ex, int ey)
{
        assert(w != NULL);
        assert(sx <= ex);
        assert(sy <= ey);
        // up
        wmove(w, sy, sx);
        wprintw(w, "+");
        for (int i = sx + 1; i < ex; ++i) {
                wprintw(w, "-");
        }
        wprintw(w, "+");
        // left right
        for (int i = sy + 1; i < ey; ++i) {
                wmove(w, i, ex);
                wprintw(w, "|");
                wmove(w, i, sx);
                wprintw(w, "|");
        }
        // down
        wmove(w, ey, sx);
        wprintw(w, "+");
        for (int i = sx + 1; i < ex; ++i) {
                wprintw(w, "-");
        }
        wprintw(w, "+");
}

int main() {
        WINDOW *w = initscr();
        for (int i = 2; i; --i) {
                // print text at a location (10,10)
                move(10, 10);
                printw("YX TEST %d", i);
                refresh();
                // let's draw a box around.
                int x, y;
                getyx(w, y, x);
                mybox(w, 9, 9, x, y + 1); // x = 10, y = 19
                refresh();
                // wait for input
                getch();
                // clear screen
                clear();
                // doing it again
        }
        endwin();
        return 0;
}
```

draws a box around a `YX TEST ?` text:

```
 +---------+
 |YX TEST 2|
 +---------+
```

If you want to have a functions which return a cursor position, just write them...

```
 int getX(WINDOW *win) {
      int x, y;
      getxy(win, y, x);
      return x;
 }

 int getY(WINDOW *win) { 
      int x, y; 
      getxy(win, y, x); 
      return y;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I'll have to digest it some more. I didn't understand the concept of windows, and how there was a default window I was printing to all along. Appreciate it!

Comment: Could you give a brief statement on how getyx(window, y, x) changes the values of x and y, when its return type is void, and the parameters are primitives (where changes should be contained in the functions "macros" scope). I'm using my knowledge of Java here, so I'm probably missing something about C that I'm not understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @greg `getxy` is macro defined like [here](https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos/ncurses/blob/master/C/curses.h#L1063). Macro is a simple preprocessor statement. Preprocessor works like `sed`, it doesn't understand types or anything, it only substitutes text. So each time you write `getxy(win, y, x)` the preprocessor subtitutes it for `(y = getcury(win), x = getcurx(win))` (on that particular implementation) and then the compiler compiles the code.

Comment: ahh ok. That makes sense. One last question: Without looking at the definition of the function / "macro", is there a way to determine if its a function or macro. For all I know, without looking at the definition of getxy, that macro is just a void function.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: No. You don't have any information about a symbol if it's not defined anywhere. And it may be a macro **and** a function, but the function declaration must come before function definition (or some preprocesor tricks are used). `void getxy(WINDOW *win, int y, int x); \n #define getxy(w, y, x) ....`. That way each time you write `getxy(win, y, x)` in your code it gets substituted with the macro, but if you want a function pointer `void (*getyx_pnt)(WINDOW*, int, int) = getxy;` you can get it anyway.

Comment: You can see that there exists a [getcury macro](https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos/ncurses/blob/master/C/curses.h#L1108) and a [getcury function](https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos/ncurses/blob/master/C/curses.h#L849).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ([legacy features](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_legacy.3x.html)) `getcury` and `getcurx`

Comment: I want this to output 2, 2, but it outputs 0, 0. What am I doing wrong?           `move(2, 2);`
`printw("cursor x is %i and y is %i", curX, curY);`
`refresh();`
`getch();`

Comment: perhaps you're passing different window-pointer to getcury/getcurx: the associated window for **`move`** is **`stdscr`**

Comment: You're right! I have to use `int wmove(WINDOW *win, int y, int x);` Using that the code above works. Is there an issue using deprecated functions? And is there a way to do the above without using the deprecated functions? Thanks.

Comment: Rather than use deprecated functions, you **could** use **`getyx`** ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided a full example, it's hard to find out, what is going wrong.

Here is a complete minimal working example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(void) {

    WINDOW * win = initscr();

    mvaddstr(10, 10, "Hello, world!");
    refresh();

    int y,x;
    getyx(win, y, x);

    // Test output two lines below
    y+=2;
    mvprintw(y, x, "X: %d, Y: %d", x, y);
    refresh();

    // press the ANY key ;-)
    getch();
    endwin();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is below right of the Hello, World! Test string and shows `X: 23 Y: 12` as expected.

Comment: @UniverseE the getyx(win, y, x) initializes (sets) the values of y and x correct, even though it has no return type? My only knowledge is from Java, so I'm confused by that structure of statements. Is that what a "macro" does? Thanks!